# Specify minimum vertical margins around all figures

Tags: spacing, floats

I would like to specify minimum vertical margins equal to the height of three single-spaced lines around all figures in a document.  By "minimum" I mean that if the figure already has this amount of space around it, then the margins should not add any more.  How do I do this?

#### MWE

Note that to use this you'll need to download my [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5r1YU.jpg) (or substitute your own).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

is reminiscent of a banana. Because there are separate hippocampi in the
left and right hemispheres, there are also two dentate gyri.

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics{hippocampus_frontal.pdf}
\caption{Hippocampal Formation (Allen Brain Explorer)}
\label{fig:HippocampusFrontal}
\end{figure}

The DG has traditionally been split into three layers visible in

\end{document}
```

#### Vertical Margins

[image]

Comment: I don't really get what do you mean. Could you please: 1) Add a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228); and 2) make a screenshot of what margin you want to change and how to change? Then it would be much easier to help you ;)

Comment: I have a feeling you may be asking the wrong question. Without a way to ensure that the bounding box of each image is the smallest it can be, there's no way for TeX to "know" how much white space an image contains.  Are the figures included by `\includegraphics` or are they generated by TikZ (or PSTricks)? What are the vertical margins relative to? Do they include the caption or not?

Comment: @AlanMunn These are figures included by `\includegraphics`. They are relative to whatever the top and bottom elements in the `figure` environment are. So in my example, that means the top of the image and the bottom of the caption. I do not expect LaTeX to account for whitespace included in the image file itself. Thanks!

Comment: \intextsep ....

Comment: @ADP Yes! That is all I was looking for. Could you please make it an answer (including the basics about what it is and how to set it) so that I can accept it. Thanks

Comment: @SeanMackesey done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As ADP correctly notes, the `\intextsep` length determines the spacing between the top and bottom of the standard floats, so changing it globally will change it for both tables and figures, which is probably not what you want.  However, you don't need to create a custom environment to have a different spacing for each; instead you can hook into the `figure` environment directly. This has the advantage that if you are using the same code for another requirement, you won't have to adjust anything other than the value.  Here's an example.  I've used the same 'image' to stand in for the tabular content that the `{table}` environment would normally contain, since it makes it easier to see the spacing difference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{\setlength{\intextsep}{3\baselineskip}}
\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{foo}
\caption{A Figure with a wide spacing}
\end{figure}
\kant[3-4]
\begin{table}[h]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{foo}
\caption{A Table with the regular spacing}
\end{table}
\kant[4]
\end{document}
```

[image: figure part]
[image: table part]

Comment: Awesome! Learn something new every day!

Answer (score 5):

The length that you are referring to is `\intextsep`, therefore, if you want to set it (globally) to something other than the default, this can be achieved via the following:

```
\setlength{\intextsep}{XYZ}
```

Where `XYZ` is your chosen dimension. Assuming you want three single-space lines, this would be achieved via the following:

```
\setlength{\intextsep}{3\baselineskip}
```

I believe that `\intextsep` affects a few other layout arrangements in the document, so perhaps you don't want to change it globally, in this case you could create a new environment which temporarily changes to your desired value, prior to restoring upon leaving the environment:

```
%DEFINE YOUR CUSTOM LENGTH
\newlength{\myintextsep}\setlength{\myintextsep}{3\baselineskip}
%CUSTOM ENVIRONMENT
\makeatletter
    \newenvironment{myfigure}[1][]{ %
        \let\intextsep@old\intextsep %
        \setlength{\intextsep}{\myintextsep} %
        \figure[#1] %
    }{ %
        \endfigure\setlength{\intextsep}{\intextsep@old} %
    }
\makeatother
```

By comparison, the difference can be seen here:

[image: Example]

With the full working code as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%DEFINE YOUR CUSTOM LENGTH
\newlength{\myintextsep}\setlength{\myintextsep}{3\baselineskip}
%CUSTOM ENVIRONMENT
\makeatletter
    \newenvironment{myfigure}[1][]{ %
        \let\intextsep@old\intextsep %
        \setlength{\intextsep}{\myintextsep} %
        \figure[#1] %
    }{ %
        \endfigure\setlength{\intextsep}{\intextsep@old} %
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
        \def\t{The cat sat on the mat }

        \t\t\t\t

        \begin{figure}[h]
            \centering\includegraphics[width=4in,height=1cm]{demo.png}
        \end{figure}

        \t\t\t\t\t

        \begin{myfigure}[h]
            \centering\includegraphics[width=4in,height=1cm]{demo.png}
        \end{myfigure}

        \t\t\t\t\t
\end{document}
```